# Understanding a datasheet

Tags: datasheet, h-bridge, specifications

Studying an IC component's datasheet, somewhere you meet electrical characteristics for the device. Device is tested under specific conditions (e.g. Vs).

How electrical characteristics are affected when conditions are different? How can I specify the new values?

In the case of [H-bridge L6205N (PowerDIP20)](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00002345.pdf), what about values of V-IL, V-IH, I-IL, I-IH, when Vs isn't 48 V but 9V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In this case of L6205N, turn to section "*Logic Inputs*" on p.8.  The input circuits (Schmitt triggers) are always powered by +5V.  The H-bridge chip has an internal regulator for the digital circuitry.  So, it turns that V-IL and V-IH are pretty much independent of the H-bridge supply voltage Vs.

[image] (Block diagram from p.1 in the datasheet.)

Often and in general, when some parameter is tangibly dependent on some other parameter, the datasheet has a chart or a formula for the dependence.  At the same time, the tables might show the parameters for some common conditions (supply voltage, temperature).

If you're reading a datasheet and suddenly think that some info is missing at the moment of reading, keep reading.  Possibly the information is further in the datasheet.  Only after you've read the whole thing and reflected upon it, you can wonder if something may be missing in the datasheet.

Often manufacturers omit some relationships, which are obvious, weak, or unimportant.  If they write them all out, the datasheet will be really bloated.  It's obvious for the manufacturer what's obvious and what isn't, but that may be less obvious for you.  Over time, you'll learn to recognize, which variations and impacts thereof may be important, and which ones are not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the part has an internal 5V regulator (see block diagram) that is used to power the inputs (see Fig. 4).  The inputs are spec'd as having TTL threshold, and I would expect that this would be valid over the entire supply voltage range.

Answer (score 1):

The logic voltage supply isn't documented very well in the data sheet but there is a clue on page 2 - it say Vin, Ven absolute maximum range is -0.3V to +7V. This implies to me that inside the chip there is a small voltage regulator that powers the logic, possibly at an internal value of 6.7V.

Looking now at the table (logic input) on page 5, it might start to make sense - to activate an input high you must raise is past 2V (1.8V typically). To deactivate it you must lower it below 0.8V (1.3V typically).

The input has hysterisis which means one you have gone above 1.8V you can't turn the relevant output off until the same input has fallen below 1.3V - it has 0.5V of hysterisis and this is to provent logic chattering away and burning your motor if the input signals are noisy.

Currents are +/-10 micro amp max into these inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the circuit as a whole and determine if there are any factors that would affect a scaling of the values.

In the specific case of this driver, the datasheet has this to say about the logic inputs (page 8):

> Pins IN1A, IN2A, IN1B and IN2B are TTL/CMOS and
>   μC compatible logic inputs. The internal structure is
>   shown in Fig. 4. Typical value for turn-on and turn-off
>   thresholds are respectively Vthon=1.8V and
>   Vthoff=1.3V.

Given that, I would say that your selected factors don't appreciably change over the entire supply range of 8V to 52V.

This is backed up by the voltage regulator in the block diagram, which most likely is used to supply the logic in the chip with a constant 5V provided that the supply voltage is within recommended operational range.

Answer (score 0):

If it were important, it would likely be in the data sheet very clearly.  The logic levels are pretty stable, usually. V-IL is unlikely to change.  V-IH is max 7v regardless of Vs (which cannot be lower than 8V).